# getting CS1056 Unexpected character '[]' error on .net core 2.0.3 web project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

When i build my .net core MVC web project i get this error 190 times :

> CS1056 Unexpected character '[]'  .

This problem is seen after a few builds. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

This is about a file in my temp folder which is on

`users\[My User]\AppData\temp\.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs`, when I delete this my project completely built.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing the issue (other than the particular file was present)?

Comment: I think this issue caused because moving MVC identity classes to another layers for our new architect.This Structural changes are changed our project from old one.

Comment: This resolved my issue and also went to delete all files starting with .Net. They got recreated after build. Thanks.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error during publishing, you can alternatively resolve the issue by creating a new release profile.